# Adding elements from two threads to the same ConcurrentLinkedQueue at the same time

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency

Assuming that Thread A tries to add an element to a ConcurrentLinkedQueue, and at the same time Thread B tries to add a different element to the same  ConcurrentLinkedQueue.

Will these two items be added to the queue, or can I have concurrency problem with that (let's say, that it is possible that only one will be inserted)?
I know that this queue is thread-safe, however I don't know if it means that I can assume that this method is also safe when I call it twice at the same time from different threads.

If it doesn't, maybe the method put/offer will be safe for this case?

Comment: The whole idea of the `Concurrent` classes is that they're thread-safe and efficient.

Comment: ...And the whole idea of a "thread safe" class is that all of its methods do "the right thing" no matter how many simultaneous calls from different threads.  What "the right thing" means in a concurrent program is not always 100% obvious, but in the case of a queue, it means at least that elements that are added won't simply disappear from the queue, and that you'll never pull an element from the queue that wasn't added.

Answer (score 0):

You can safely add elements to `ConcurrentLinkedQueue` at the same time from different threads. All elements will be in a queue. If you call `add()` method from two threads once per thread you will have two elements in a queue. There is no method `put()` in the interface of `ConcurrentLinkedQueue`. Method `add()` do the same as `offer()`. You can see this at the source

```
/**
 * Inserts the specified element at the tail of this queue.
 * As the queue is unbounded, this method will never throw
 * {@link IllegalStateException} or return {@code false}.
 *
 * @return {@code true} (as specified by {@link Collection#add})
 * @throws NullPointerException if the specified element is null
 */
public boolean add(E e) {
    return offer(e);
}
```

Comment: tnx. and it counts for all adding method of the queue?             (add and offer methods)